# in xcode auto select the real device when connected to laptop

Tags: iphone, xcode

In android studio, if you connect android phone to laptop, phone gets auto selected. Now if you run your project, it runs on auto selected phone.
Is there similar functionality in xcode? Currently if i connect a device to laptop, in xcode i need to always select the connected device manually to run the project on that device.

Comment: Been primarily developing for iOS for years now and this has always driven me mad, hope someone has an answer.

Comment: It's 2021, and this feature still isn't available in Xcode 13. Every time the device disconnects (for example, because of an accidental disconnect with slight movement in charge cradle) you have to select it again. It's starting to annoy me too.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think XCode will automatically select the connected device. Before connecting the device one of the simulator is our default device. After connecting your physical device you have to change it manually.

It's also mentioned in Developer Documentation, you can check it here : https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/RunningonaDevice.html

Comment: Maybe next year will be the year Apple adds this feature. If we're back to in-person WWDC by then this would be one of those "standing ovation" announcements.

Comment: I hope so. It would be a small feature but its required one

Comment: No luck with those hopes. Let's see if Xcode 14 in 2022 will finally have this feature...